# $T(n/2 +1)$ substitution in recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relation

How to find the recurrence relation using domain range substitution method for the below:
$$
T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2} +1\right) + n -2
$$

I am unable to get a pattern with this relation as it is really confusing. I am guessing the below for $T(n/2 + 1)$:
$$
T\left(\frac{n}{2} +1\right) = 2T\left(\frac{n+2}{4}+1\right)+ \frac{n+2}{2} - 2
$$

When I substitute this for $T(n)$ it becomes a mess.

Can someone guide me in this please.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can spot the pattern here:
\begin{align}
T(n) &= 2T\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right) + n-2 \\ &=
4T\left(\frac{n+6}{4}\right) + 2n-4 \\ &=
8T\left(\frac{n+14}{8}\right) + 3n-6 \\ &=
16T\left(\frac{n+30}{16}\right) + 4n-8
\end{align}
More generally, we have
$$
T(n) = 2^k T\left(\frac{n-2}{2^k} + 2\right) + k(n-2).
$$
This implies that
$$
T(2^k+2) = 2^k T(3) + k2^k.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Making $S(n) = T(n+a)$ we have

$$
S(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n+a}{2}+1\right)+n+a-2
$$

but

$$
T\left(\frac{n+a}{2}+1\right) = S\left(\frac{n+a}{2}+1-a\right) = S\left(\frac n2-\frac a2+1\right)
$$

now choosing $a=2$ we follow with

$$
S(n)=2S\left(\frac n2\right)+n
$$

etc.